# Display None CSS not working in Mac OS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am using `display:none` in my css and its working fine in windows browsers but in mac os its showing all the things I have made display as none. Please suggest some solutions.

Sample Code:

```
 <div>
     <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Width="110px" Text="Find" Font-Names="Candara"
                Height="25px" CssClass="clrBtn" OnClick="btnFind_Click" />
      <div id="DivFind" runat="server" class="white_content" style="left: 12%; top: 22%">
            <asp:Label ID="findLight" runat="server" Text="Find" CssClass="subheading" Font-Names="Candara">
            </asp:Label>

        </div>
        <div id="findFade" class="black_overlay" runat="server">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgeditclose" AlternateText="close" runat="server"
                align="right" CssClass="imgMultiListingsfadeCSS" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .white_content
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 22%;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 0px solid #a6c25c;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:300px;
}
.black_overlay
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

C#:

```
 protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DivFind.Style.Add("display", "block");
        findFade.Style.Add("display", "block");

    }
```

Here I am adding two divs for creating light-box effect and displaying that in code behind on button click. Its working fine in my windows OS.

Thanks.

Comment: What code exactly doesn´t work for you? I have no problem with display: none in mac browsers.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please share us your CSS code so that we can help you.

Comment: Edited the question with code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

With the current information it's a bit hard to debug. However you can open the developer tools in the browser (Chrome ⌘⌥i) and see what is happening. It could be something is overriding something else.